# Is it possible to map a higher order function in kotlin to a string

Tags: android, kotlin

I have to make an async request, and then notify the result to the listeners involved.

```
fun connectToTopic(topic:String, body:(topic:String, data : ByteArray ) -> Void){
topicCallbackMap.put(topic, body) // is this possible???
    }
```

I want to create a map from "topic" to the higher order function, so that I can call the particular higher order function for a particular topic, like this

```
private val topicCallbackMap: Map<String, body:(topic:String, data : ByteArray ) -> Void>
```

The above one is a wrong code, just wanted to give the essence.

What I want can be easily achieved by using an interface listener, but I wanted to know if this is possible in Kotlin. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. There are only some syntax errors on your code. And note that you need a `MutableMap` in order to put value into the map.

```
private val topicCallbackMap = mutableMapOf<String, (String, ByteArray) -> Unit>()

fun connectToTopic(topic:String, body: (String, ByteArray) -> Unit) {
    topicCallbackMap.put(topic, body)
    //OR
    topicCallbackMap[topic] = body
}
```

Answer (score 3):

yes this is possible:

```
val functionMap: Map<String, (Int) -> Int> =
        mapOf("a2" to { a: Int -> a * 2 },
                "a3" to {a: Int -> a * 3} )

fun execute(a: Int, myBlock: (Int) -> Int) {
    println( myBlock(a) )
}
```

Than you can get the function out of the map and use it as parameter for another function:

```
val fun1 = functionMap["a2"]

if (fun1 != null) {
    execute(3, fun1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help some other person. Here it is, more readable code with typealias.

```
private val topicCallbackMap = mutableMapOf<String,SomeFunc>()

fun connectToTopic(topic:String, body: SomeFunc) {
    topicCallbackMap[topic] = body
}

typealias SomeFunc = (String, ByteArray) -> Unit


fun execution(){
    //Adding to Map
    connectToTopic("foo"){a:String,b:ByteArray-> println(a)}
    connectToTopic("bar"){a:String,b:ByteArray-> println(a+b.joinToString("")) }
    //Execution
    topicCallbackMap["foo"]?.invoke("Foo Printed:", byteArrayOf())
    topicCallbackMap["bar"]?.invoke("Bar Printed printed with ByteArray:", byteArrayOf(12))


}
```

Output:

```
Foo Printed
Bar Printed printed with ByteArray:12
```